# Should I use .ToString() when concatenating string and integer variables in C#?

Tags: c#

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int sum = a + b;
string expression = "Expression: " + a + " + " + b + " = " + sum;
Console.WriteLine(expression); //displays Expression 1 + 2 = 3
```

Should I use:

```
string expression = "Expression: " + a + " + " + b + " = " + sum;
```

or

```
string expression = "Expression: " + a.ToString() + " + " + b.ToString() + " = " + result.ToString();
```

Is it recommended to use `ToString()` when concatenating `string` and `int`?

Comment: In `a + "" + b + ""` or `"" + a + b + ""`, it doesn't matter: it's all string concatenation. In `a + b + ""` it does matter: `a` and `b` are added first.

Comment: Side note: In VB.NET, this ambiguity is avoided by having an explicit [string concatenation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx): `"Expression: " + a` will throw a compile time error (with Option Strict On), `"Expression: " & a` will perform string concatenation.

Comment: The first code will result in boxing (int to Int32), the second one does not. The second one is obviously faster.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### `ToString` usage

No, you shouldn't use `ToString` here.

String concatenation automatically transforms non-strings into strings, which means that your two variants are nearly¹ identical:

> When one or both operands are of type string, the predefined addition operators concatenate the string representation of the operands.

<sup>Source: [C# Language Specification: Addition operator, MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979).</sup>

On the other hand, the first one (without `ToString`):

- Is shorter to write,
- Is shorter to read,
- Is easier to maintain and:
- shows exactly the intention of the author: to concatenate strings.

So prefer the first one.

### Under the hood

What is also interesting is to see what happens under the hood. One of the ways to see it is to watch the IL code within LINQPad. This program:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = 3;
    var b = " Hello";
    var c = a + b;
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

is translated to the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldstr       " Hello"
IL_0008:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_000A:  box         System.Int32
IL_000F:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0010:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_0015:  stloc.2     // c
IL_0016:  ldloc.2     // c
IL_0017:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

See that `System.String.Concat`? That means that the original code can be written also like that, which translates into exactly same IL:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = 3;
    var b = " Hello";
    var c = string.Concat(a, b); // This is the line which was changed.
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

When you read [the documentation of `string.Concat(object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1(v=vs.110).aspx), you may learn that:

> The method concatenates each object in *args* by calling the parameterless `ToString` method of that object; it does not add any delimiters.

This means that `ToString` is redundant. Also:

> `String.Empty` is used in place of any null object in the array.

Which handles nicely the case where some of the operands are null (see the footnote 1).

While in the last example, concatenation was translated into `string.Concat`, one should also highlight compiler optimizations:

```
var a = "Hello " + "World";
```

is translated into:

```
ldstr       "Hello World"
stloc.0
```

On the other hand:

```
var a = string.Concat("Hello ", "World");
```

is translated into:

```
ldstr       "Hello "
ldstr       "World"
call        System.String.Concat
stloc.0
```

### Other alternatives

There are of course other ways to concatenate string representations of objects in C#.

1. [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) is used when you need to do a lot of concatenation operations and helps reducing the number of intermediary strings created. Deciding whether you should use a `StringBuilder` or an ordinary concatenation may not be easy. Use a profiler or search for relevant answers on Stack Overflow.

   Using `StringBuilder` has a major drawback of making the code difficult to read and maintain. For simple cases as the one in your question, `StringBuilder` is not only harmful to the readability of the code, but also useless in terms of performance.
2. `string.Join` should be used when you need to add delimiters.

   Obviously, never use `string.Join` with an empty delimiter to concatenate strings.
3. `string.Format` can be used when string templating is preferred to string concatenation. One of the cases where you may prefer that is when the message may be localized, as suggested in the answer by kunthet.

   Using `string.Format` has several drawbacks which makes it unsuited for simple cases like yours:

   - With simple "{0}" placeholders, it is often unclear which parameter goes where. It is frequent to mistakenly reverse the parameters or to forget one. Luckily, [C# 6 finally introduces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/new-features-in-c-6) string interpolation which solves this problem.
   - Runtime performance may degrade. Of course, don't assume `string.Format` is *always* slower. If performance matters, measure two approaches and determine which one is faster based on your actual results instead of assumptions.
   - The code is slightly longer to write, longer to read and harder to maintain, although this is extremely minor and shouldn't bother you too much.

---

<sup>¹ The difference appears when one of the objects is `null`. Without `ToString`, a `null` is replaced by an empty string. With `ToString`, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown.</sup>

Comment: For exactly this reason (unpredictable behaviour), concatenating strings with the `+` is considered bad practice in most languages. In this case I'd use `string.Concat`, in many cases `string.Format` is better. It's certainly not Pythonic to use `+`, and since PEP 3101 `%` is discouraged as well in favour of `str.format`.

Comment: Is substituting an empty string for `null` really "handling it nicely"? Well, it's not as bad as "on error resume next"...

Comment: Under the hood, if you concatenate without calling .ToString(), boxing will happen..., and `Concat(object[])` will be used instead of `Concat(string[])`. So `"string " + i` is not actually identical to `"string " + i.ToString()`

Comment: @RandomAlphabets: valid point. However, the difference is simply the location of `ToString()`: OP's code in one case, `System.String.Concat`'s implementation in the other case. So, the answer remains valid: don't write the code which has no benefit.

Answer (score 15):

Instead, you should use string formatter. It's easier to format your number into string representation or localization. e.g.:

```
string expression = string.Format("Expression: {0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, sum);
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, string formatter is less readable (and maybe also performance) than string concatenation.

Comment: Care to explain why this option is better?

Comment: @WorldEngineer: I updated the explanation.

Comment: I don't know about everyone else, but I actually find this more readable. Maybe because I grew up with C where s[n]printf is the only realistic option for this kind of code.

Comment: But this way gives three sources of mistakes instead of one. When you add something into the string, you 1) have to change the format string, 2) have not to forget to add new parameter in the list, 3) try to pick the correct spot in the list where new parameter should be placed.

Comment: Just wanna chime in and let you know about the upcoming string interpolation feature in C# 6.. You will write "Expression: \{a} + \{b} = \{sum}" to get the same result. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/846566/What-s-new-in-Csharp-String-Interpolation

Comment: It can be more readable in that the line won't be cluttered with plus signs and quotation marks (and thus much less noise). But it's harder to read in that the variables are at the end of the line (if there's a lot of variables, it's hard to know which numbers are which from a quick glance). It's more powerful for formatting, though. I prefer this approach only when I need the more powerful formatting or for translation strings (where the location of variables may be changed).

Answer (score -2):

If you use `+` concatenation, it itself uses `String.Concat` method. String itself doesn't expose a + operator.

for example:

```
int i = 10;
string str = "hello" + i;
```

is compiled into:

```
int i = 10;
object o1 = "hello";
object o2 = i; // Note boxing
string str = string.Concat(o1, o2);
```

If you directly call `ToString`, it will avoid boxing and call the `Concat(string, string)` overload. Hence the `ToString` call will be slightly more efficient although not significant enough. You better go with the example you feel is more readable.

Comment: this seems to merely repeat points made and explained in [prior answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/266370/31260): "String concatenation automatically transforms non-strings into strings..."